# How to setup firebase realtime DB authentication using only one account for all the users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, proguard

In my android app I don't want users to login individually yet. I want to set one single account for authentication for all the users to read and write data to Firebase realtime database. I will have to write username and password inside the code. if I use proguard will it be possible for anyone to decompile and see this authentication info? I am asking because proguard doesn't mask everything. and also is this a good way to do authentication using single account?

I have searched for possible solution regarding this. But found no answer. Everyone does user logins and use that info for authentication.

Comment: If the user name and password need to be known in the app, they can be extracted by a user. Even when you encrypt them: when that encryption has to be reversible, it can also be performed by a user of your app. But this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish by using auth, but not requiring your users to sign in as themselves?

Comment: I'm trying to add in app purchase which will be device specific. Meaning no multi device support. So I'm identifying each user by device id. That's why not wanting to make user go through a signing up process. Keeping the in app purchase info in Firebase so that reinstalling or clearing data will not also remove users purchase info. Can you please elaborate on how user can extract that account info from the app? Or maybe some links to read about regarding this. Thanks very much for the informative reply.

Comment: If somebody gets access to the device (e.g. steals it), they can decompile the APK and extract the data from there. Whether it's worth their effort is hard to say, but technically: anything that you application code has access to, is something a malicious user can access too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is Authenticate with Firebase anonymously.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

Answer (score -1):

By default, your database rules require Firebase Authentication and grant full read and write permissions only to authenticated users. The default rules ensure your database isn't accessible by just anyone before you get a chance to configure it. Once you're set up, you can customize your rules to your needs. Here are some common examples:

```
// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
// read and write access to your database
{
 "rules": {
 ".read": true,
 ".write": true
 }
}
```

Now, without Authentication all your users access data, but this not best way to use database.

reference [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer my question at all!